# Django + Djangae + Nose / Fail wsgi

Tags: python, django, nose

I'm currently trying to setting up django-nose in my project.

I also used Djangae (https://djangae.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for app engine compatibility.

I add 'django_nose' in my INSTALLED_APPS
I set TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'

Launching "python manage.py test" is not raising any exceptions.

But when I want to launch the server with "python manage.py runserver", the server is running but when I try to call "localhost:8000" I get :

```
            ERROR    2016-03-23 15:59:49,299 wsgi.py:263]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/briva/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
        handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
      File "/Users/briva/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
        handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
      File "/Users/briva/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 96, in LoadObject
        __import__(cumulative_path)
      File "/Users/briva/Desktop/dangoptest/dangoptest/wsgi.py", line 18, in <module>
        application = DjangaeApplication(get_wsgi_application())
      File "/Users/briva/Desktop/dangoptest/lib/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
        django.setup()
      File "/Users/briva/Desktop/dangoptest/lib/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
        apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
      File "/Users/briva/Desktop/dangoptest/lib/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
        app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
      File "/Users/briva/Desktop/dangoptest/lib/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
        module = import_module(entry)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
        __import__(name)
      File "lib/django_nose/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
        from django_nose.runner import BasicNoseRunner, NoseTestSuiteRunner
      File "lib/django_nose/runner.py", line 61, in <module>
        from django.test.simple import DjangoTestSuiteRunner as DiscoverRunner
    ImportError: No module named simple
```

Thanks for answers.

Comment: Have you installed it to the same virtualenv you're running the server from?